# To Perform An Action When Clicking a Button in JavaFX

Tags: java

I am trying to make a project. My project contains a package and all classes are included in it. Every class is created by extending the Application class to each one. Also there is the start() method to which the object of Stage is passed, in every class. Each class performs each function. Each function is performed when clicking on corresponding button. How can I perform actions by clicking each button ?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question - but I think what you're looking for is an [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) .

Comment: There should be only one class that extends the `Application` class.

Comment: K..then how will I make my other classes ? I code my program using netbeans. All programs extends the Application class. How can i make classes without using application ?